# Simple database connection in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, razor

I would like to make a very simple page that reads and displays data from a (SQL Server) database.

I've been messing with ASP.NET MVC, but for what I want (a quick solution in a single, simple webpage) this seems like overkill. Razor WebPages seems a better solution.

The database object from WebMatrix.Data seems good, but I cannot get this to work in Visual Studio Express 2013. I keep on getting "The type or namespace name 'WebMatrix' cound not be found", even though I added WebMatrix.Data to the References of the project.

I've also tried using Entity Framework (even though that also seems like overkill), but that comes with other cryptic errors like "A namespace cannot directly contain memebers such as fields or methods" (with the error message leading to a source file that only contains "ErrorGeneratingOutput").

I really can't understand why this needs to be so difficult? I just want to quickly output some records from a database onto a webpage, nothing fancy.

Comment: So... is there a question here??

Comment: Yes. How do I make a simple database connection? Like I say, I cannot get it to work with either WebMatrix.Data or with Entity Framework.

Comment: LightSwitch was perhaps created for folks like you

Comment: Um, have you considered plain vanilla ASP.NET/ADO.NET? Open connection get data into DataTable, bind DataTable to a GridView? Why this needs to be so difficult indeed?

Comment: I've been using ASP.NET Web Forms and ADO.NET in the past (and had many problems with the various events in databinding), and from what I see, Razor seems much more lightweight. Is Razor not as simple as it looks?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution; I had to install the "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages Web Data" package using nuget.

I have not found any documentation on this; the StackOverflow answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870874/72809 was the only one that pointed me in the right direction. It's still very unclear to me when one has to use "Add Reference" and when one has to use nuget, but I'm happy this problem is solved for now...

Comment: I would very much like to know why the solution got downvoted. Is it not right?