# How to reference dbdatabase in .net 4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-framework-version, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm working on an mvc project conversion and updating the framework from 4.0 to 4.7.1.

The project uses a DbDatabase class (`System.Data.Entity.Database.Dbdatabase`) but none of the references that I've tried adding will work (`System.Data.Entity.Database`, `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`, Matrix, etc.)

I've also tried adding different Entity Frameworks versions available using NuGet, and the old EntityFramework.dll (v 4.0.0.0), but still get the same error - "The name 'DbDatabase' does not exist in the current context."

The line that's giving an error is:

`DbDatabase.SetInitializer<CoreEntityDB>(new NoActionDbInitializer<CoreEntityDB>());`

Can this still be used in 4.7.1?
`

Comment: does this help ?? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547158/the-name-database-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: No, I tried adding WebMatrix, but that didn't work either.

Comment: did you tried the other answers ?

Comment: just finished trying the different suggestions. No luck :(